# How to get current logged in user's local timezone in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I need to get current logged in user's local timezone and pass it to a function which exports an excel data for analysis purpose.

The export to excel data functionality is done using server side code, and I need to get the logged in user's local timezone from client machine.

Can any one help me to provide way to resolve this issue?

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need a plugin of some kind (i.e.: flash, or Active-X). The timezone of the client isn't in the HTTP request header and you can't access system information like that from a page rendered in a browser.

If your users don't travel around too much, you could save their timezones to their profiles.

edit: I've seen people talking about solving this kind of problem before, by getting the user's approximate location and then inferring the time zone from that. It should be noted that this workaround may be extremely innacurate.